# Shell wildcard/glob for optional string in a makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, glob

I'm trying to "optimize" my 'clean' target in multi-platform Makefiles so I was looking for a way to remove executable files with or without the Windows-extension `.exe`.

Of course, you could do

```
rm file file.exe
```

but I was looking for something like

```
rm file(.exe)?
```

I also tried

```
rm file{,.exe}
```

which doesn't work either.

I was surprised to see that what I tried did not work, so I'm mostly posting this to learn more about globing, as the version with the two explicit filenames works fine.

Comment: Amended title and tag to specify use of `make`, as writing code for a makefile *even when it will eventually be executed by a shell* tends to be substantially different from writing content for direct shell interpretation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for that. Although I was thinking I could learn something about general shell globing too. But better to keep the question to the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make executes commands with `/bin/sh` by default, which has limited globbing support.

```sh
$ cat Makefile 
test:
    echo foo{bar,baz}
$ make
echo foo{bar,baz}
foo{bar,baz}
```

If you want fancy features like curly braces to work you'll need to switch the shell by setting `SHELL`.

```sh
$ cat Makefile 
SHELL = /bin/bash

test:
    echo foo{bar,baz}
$ make
echo foo{bar,baz}
foobar foobaz
```

I wouldn't necessarily advise doing so as it makes your Makefile less portable.

For what it's worth, [GNU Automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/)'s strategy is to set an `EXEEXT` variable based on the platform. Then the clean rule is:

```
rm -f file$(EXEEXT)
```

Comment: Agreed, I don't want to switch shell. So this kinda indicates that I can't do what I want in the way that I figured. Your comment about Automake was the trigger for a better solution in the Makefile. I already had EXEEXT implemented in another project, but did not think about it. I'll accept this as the answer since this helped me with a "solution" to the "problem".